# How to make cloth move by collision objects?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, soft-body

I am having a trouble when animating a wedding dress.

For better simulation, I chose to make my wedding dress as a softy body instead of cloth.
Then, to make my dress follow my character during animation, I did weight painting for the whole dress : particularly, the whole bottom of the dress is weight painted on the hips, instead of the legs, foots...
The reason is because I want to let the bottom free.

Now here is the problem : when the legs of my character move, they go through the dress, so that's very ugly.
I don't understand, because I make my character as a collision.

So to sum up, how is it possible to have my dress follow my character during animation, and to let the bottom free that can move only by collision with the legs of my character ?

Thank you

Comment: Don't expect a soft body to look like a cloth. They may be similar, but they are different. [The Blender Manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/physics/cloth/introduction.html) has this to say: "Blender’s Softbody system provides better simulation of closed meshes; Cloth is a specialized simulation of fabrics." There are probably some video tutorials out there that can instruct you on how to do cloth simulations on character clothing.